# REST API - POST method in Vanilla JavaScript/AJAX - Error 400 (Bad request)

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

can you please help me how to get to work POST method in vanilla JS (without jQuery)?

I am trying to do it with this code:

```
var call =
{
  "filterParameters": {
    "id": 18855843,
    "isInStockOnly": false,
    "newsOnly": false,
    "wearType": 0,
    "orderBy": 0,
    "page": 1,
    "params": {
      "tId": 0,
      "v": []
    },
    "producers": [],
    "sendPrices": true,
    "type": "action",
    "typeId": "",
    "branchId": ""
  }
};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.alza.cz/Services/RestService.svc/v2/products');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('OK ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
    else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(call);
```

And constantly getting error 400 (Bad request).
I have tried to call it in jQuery and it is working, but I need to get it work in plain JS.

Please, any idea why it is not working?

For check, here is the working code in jQuery:

```
addData({
  "filterParameters": {
    "id": 18855843,
    "isInStockOnly": false,
    "newsOnly": false,
    "wearType": 0,
    "orderBy": 0,
    "page": 1,
    "params": {
      "tId": 0,
      "v": []
    },
    "producers": [],
    "sendPrices": true,
    "type": "action",
    "typeId": "",
    "branchId": ""
  }
}
);

function addData(data){// pass your data in method
     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "https://www.alza.cz/Services/RestService.svc/v2/products",
             data: JSON.stringify(data),// now data come in this function
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             crossDomain: true,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

                 console.log(data);// write success in " "
             },

             error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                 // error handler
                 console.log(jqXHR);
                 alert('fail' + status.code);
             }
          });
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to `JSON.stringify(call)`

Comment: @Tomos Williams thank you for the tip, I tried the `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(call));` but no luck.. still error 400

Comment: What's the response you're getting?
Can you check the preview of your request in the network tab in your browser's developers tools?

Comment: Compare your request to a working request, you are probably sending the wrong body or headers

Comment: @Endless request working in jQuery is completely the same, so the error must be somewhere in the calling the POST request

Comment: @Endless I have added working jQuery code to the original question for compare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the `content-type` header to `application/json` 
 You are posting json data as formdata which is wrong
 (beside you have forgotten to stringify your object)

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Heres is a working example using the new vanilla js fetch API

```
var result = null

fetch("https://www.alza.cz/Services/RestService.svc/v2/products", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "filterParameters": {
      "id": 18855843,
      "isInStockOnly": false,
      "newsOnly": false,
      "wearType": 0,
      "orderBy": 0,
      "page": 1,
      "params": {
        "tId": 0,
        "v": []
      },
      "producers": [],
      "sendPrices": true,
      "type": "action",
      "typeId": "",
      "branchId": ""
    }
  }),
  headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
  //credentials: 'include'
})
.then(function(res) {
  if (res.ok) { // ok if status is 2xx
    console.log('OK ' + res.statusText);
  } else {
    console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + res.status);
  }

  return res.blob()
})
.then(function(blob) {
  result = blob
  // window.result = blob
})
```

Comment: Figured if you used a chrome extension i could as well write it using fetch api (which is not supported in IE btw) Personal prefer fetch/promise over XHR

Comment: I have read that Access-Control-Allow-Origin block can be solved by using JSONP instead of JSON...

Comment: You can't make any other then `GET` request when doing `jsonp`. jsonp will insert a javascript with a callback

Comment: Please on more question - how can I save the fetch result to variable? I tried something with blob() and asigning to new variable but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response blocking the Javascript code to AJAX access the server data. If the server is not controlled by you, you need another server to fetch the data instead, before it can redirect to your webpage.

Comment: it is not the error - I have overwritten security setting in Chrome using CORS plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

So I just tried `xhr.send()`

and got

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.alza.cz/Services/RestService.svc/v2/products. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.alza.cz' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

However if I try this on a blank tab, it actually works.
what url are you trying to run this JS from?

Try running the JS from a blank tab.

Comment: it is not the error - I have overwritten security setting in Chrome using CORS plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). I am getting error 400. Here is the screenshot (https://s4.postimg.org/xkqxiiqq5/Sn_mek_obrazovky_2017-07-10_v_15.37.32.png)